# Matplotlib.pyplot isn't working

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, matplotlib

I'm using python3 on ubuntu and I have this problem:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:273: UserWarning: Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.
  warnings.warn('Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.')
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:273: UserWarning: Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.
  warnings.warn('Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.')
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3agg.py:18: UserWarning: The Gtk3Agg backend is known to not work on Python 3.x with pycairo. Try installing cairocffi.
  "The Gtk3Agg backend is known to not work on Python 3.x with pycairo. "
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you actually *read* the error? It tells you exactly what to do. Googling the warnings will give you more information about them. At least *try* to address the problem yourself before asking here.

Comment: "The Gtk3Agg backend is known to not work on Python 3.x with pycairo. Try installing cairocffi". Did you try that yet?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the Gtk3Agg backend that you might want to look into is Tinker. To give an example: (Using `Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux`)

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(10))
plt.show()
```

This produces the plot as expected.

You can make python use this by default by entering the following into the console (or into your `.bashrc` file): `export MPLBACKEND="TkAgg"`.